# If A and B are equivalent matrices, is it always true that rank(A)=rank(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that if A and B are similar matrices, then they are matrix representations of a certain linear operator. Hence, rank(A)=rank(B) is always true for this case.

But when it comes to the case when A and B are equivalent matrices, I'm not sure if this still holds.

Comment: Surely you have seen [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalent_Matrices_have_Equal_Rank)? On this site we also have it, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170454/proving-two-linear-operators-are-equivalent-iff-they-have-the-same-rank).

Answer (score 2):

You have $B = Q^{-1}AP$, where $P$ and $Q$ are invertible. Hence,
$$
\operatorname{Im}B = \operatorname{Im}(Q^{-1}A) = Q^{-1}\operatorname{Im}A.
$$
Hence, if you have a basis of $\operatorname{Im}A$, it gets mapped one-to-one (by $Q^{-1}$) to a basis of $\operatorname{Im}B$, which implies
$$
\operatorname{rank}B = \dim\operatorname{Im}B = \dim\operatorname{Im}A = \operatorname{rank}A.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Invertable  matrices are products of elementary matrices, which preserve the rank since multiplying by them is the same as preforming an elementary operations.

Comment: ok, so  what is your issue with this answer ?